# COUNT DISTINCT in QUERY of Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is the query I am trying to perform with the QUERY function:

```
=QUERY(DATA!A2:H;"select Col1,Col2,Col3, count(Col4) group by Col1,Col2,Col3 ")
```

I expected it to count Col4 values, but that the repeated ones would only be counted once.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Here is an example that is very similar [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sz2CBsVO6QkqoA5ThBHI4hTZqR80UUKnI5-0NGcijTk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=query({DATA!A2:C\byrow(DATA!A2:C;lambda(Σ;if(countif(byrow(DATA!A2:index(DATA!C:C;row(Σ));lambda(Λ;join(;Λ)));join(;Σ))=1;1;)))};
   "Select Col1, Col2, sum(Col4), count(Col3) group by Col1, Col2 label sum(Col4) '',count(Col3)'' ")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the sheet

Comment: Updated answer for the fresh requirements

Comment: I wish there was something in the language like: 'select count(distinct Col1)' . u.u